# How to reference jQuery plugin instance dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, self

Within my jQuery plugin execution flow I render this sidebar list of links.

```
//render method
var render = function(self){

  var sidebar = '';
  var main = '';

  /* Sidebar */        
  sidebar += '<ul>'
  sidebar += '<li><a href="javascript:self.data(activeFolder,1);self.data(render);">Rootobject 1</a></li>';

}
```

Only I don't want the link to print out `self`, but I want a reference to the object referenced by self instead.

------------- UPDATE ------------

I'll try to explain my problem in a different way.

If I had been working with this plugin from the body of the page, I could easily store a reference to it upon init

```
var myPlugin = $('.some-element').myPlugin();
```

and later do this:

```
<a href="javascript:myPlugin.render();">Rootobject 1</a>
```

Now, I want my plugin to prepare that same link, so how can I write a refrence from within the plugin to substitute the myPlugin var in this example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this by following the best practice of removing obtrusive javascript anyway.

You can setup a delegate handler so event handling isn't tied to a specific element.  Just setup a handler on the `body` element which will never get added or removed.  Click events will eventually bubble up to body, then pass in a selector so you just pay attention to clicks that meet your criteria like this:

```
$("body").on('click', ".sidebar a", function() {
  $(this).data(activeFolder, 1)
         .data(render);
});
```

Comment: But the point is to write out the reference in the link dynamically, in case there are several plugin instances at the same time. Also, if I add a handler as you suggest, every time the list in the sidebar is updated (by this render method) that handler would have to be reassigned.

Comment: @MattiasSvensson, then you can use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: And for solving the multiple instance issue, I would probably have to substitute your ".sidebar a" above with "#myInstanceElementsId .sidebar a" right?

Comment: @MattiasSvensson, sure! There are lots of possible solutions.  You could have a parent element that stored the data attributes you needed for each instance.  Once in the event handler, use `$(this).closest()` to get the parent and grab whatever context sensitive info you need.  That's a much more *plugin* friendly way of doing things.